# Saved files no longer exists after closing the app

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, afnetworking-2, nslibrarydirectory

I am downloading a file using NSURLSessionDownloadTask. it get downloaded and saved. and I can display data normally.

Unfortunitly I only have the iOS simulator to test. What is happenning if I close the app with the stop button on Xcode. then I relaunch, the file is no longer exists.

But, If I closed it by removing it from apps. running list by clicking cmd + shift + H twice. and reluanch it by tapping app. on simulator. I find the file.

```
BOOL found = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];
```

Is this a simulator problem? and I shouldn't worry about it in a real device?

Actually, I just managed to test on iPhone. exactly the same behaviour!! Any explanation.

I call this on the `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` which I sent a destination block that returns the destination to save:

```
- (NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                             progress:(NSProgress * __autoreleasing *)progress
                                          destination:(NSURL * (^)(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response))destination
                                    completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error))completionHandler
```

Destination block code:

```
NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to log `documentsDirectoryURL` and you will see that it is different each time you launch the app. Solution is to save between launches not an absolute URL, but a path relative to NSLibraryDirectory directory. I had the same problem and I have solved it with two methods:

```
// [self uploadFolder] returns a folder in NSLibraryDirectory
+ (NSString*)relativePathForURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    NSURL *uploadFolderURL = [self uploadFolder];
    if ([url.baseURL isEqual:uploadFolderURL])
    {
        return url.relativeString;
    }
    else if ([url.absoluteString hasPrefix:uploadFolderURL.absoluteString])
    {
        return [url.absoluteString substringFromIndex:uploadFolderURL.absoluteString.length];
    }
    return nil;
}

+ (NSURL*)urlForRelativePath:(NSString*)path
{
    return [NSURL URLWithString:path relativeToURL:[self uploadFolder]];
}
```

They should be used following way:

1. Download file and move it to NSLibraryDirectory folder with some URL
   `savedURL`.
2. Call `relativePath = [self relativePathForURL:savedURL]` and save it.
3. When app is relaunched call `savedURL = [self urlForRelativePath:relativePath]`
4. `savedURL` is valid now.

Comment: it already gert saved to NSDocumentDirectory. I updated question please check

Comment: Thank you man. even I didnt test or used ur solution. but I got the idea that in everyrun the LibraryDirectory path changes. my mistake was that I was saving the full path of the file in userdefaults and gets it from there when I want. As u mentioned I only should save the part after the LibraryDirectory part in the full path (RelativePath).

Answer (score 0):

Heres the solution;

```
 - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location{

    //location is the temporary "destination" which you returned (can be Temp directory) and it now contains the downloaded file. Now copy the file to a new location (eg documents directory) for future use.

     BOOL fileCopied = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:location toURL:documentsDirectoryURLForSavingFileForFutureUe error:&error];


    }
```